# Python data structure literals

Tags: javascript, python

In JavaScript I know of 2 data structure literals:

a) Object literal => {}, for example

```
{ "first": "peter", "last": "miller }
```

b) Array literal => [], for example

```
[ 4, 7, 8 ]
```

In JavaScript I like those literals because they are compact and easily readable.

I have read that Python also has some:

Array literal:

```
[] => [ 4, 5 ]
```

Dictionary literal:

```
{ "first": "peter", "last": "miller" }
```

Tuple literals:

```
() => (45, 69)
```

Are those Python literals comparable to JavaScript literals?

Are there more Python data structure literals?

Is there any difference between the dictionary literal and dict(...)?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Are those Python literals comparable to JavaScript literals?

Basically Yes.

JS: `[1, 2, ,4]  => [1, 2, undefined, 4]`
Python: `[1, 2, , 4]  => invalid syntax`

JS: `{key: 'value'}`
Python: `{key: 'value'}  => name 'key' is not defined`

> Are there more Python data structure literals?

Set:
{1, 2, 3} <=> set([1, 2, 3])

> Is there any difference between the dictionary literal and dict(...)?

No

Comment: Why are Python literals not comparable to JavaScript literals?

Comment: Why does Python code not work in JavaScript and vice versa?

Answer (score 1):

**Q.** Are those Python literals comparable to JavaScript literals?

```
   JS objects are comparable to Python dicts
   JS arrays are comparable to Python arrays
```

**Q.** Are there more Python data structure literals?

```
   Yes.  
   Python has tuples:  (10, 20, 30)
   Python has sets:    {10, 20, 30}
```

**Q.** Is there any difference between the dictionary literal and dict(...)?

```
   If you mean, a difference between JS and Python, the answer is Yes.
   JS dictionaries (objects) must have a string as a key.
   Python can use other types as a key.
   JS object literals do not allow a trailing comma.

   If you mean, a difference between Python literals and the dict() constructor,
   the answer depends on how you use the dict contructor.
   dict(a=1, b=2)        # only allows keys to be valid identifiers that aren't keywords
   dict([('x y', 0), ('def', 1), (12, 'tw')])  # is more flexible
   {'x y': 0, 'def': 1, 12: 'tw'} # is flexible and equivalent
```

**P.S.**

```
   The are other JS versus Python differences besides the containers.
   Python has "True".  JS has "true"
   Python has "None".  JS has "none"
   Python has four string quoting characters: ' " ''' """
```